# RedShift: Unnest subquery's result on leader is not supported

Tags: amazon-redshift

I try to parse JSON in RedShift.

My string in column "inputs" is:

```
[{"desc": "How many people does the video contain?", "name": "Number of People", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Only 1", "2-3", "3+"]}, {"desc": "What is the camera position?", "name": "Movement", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Fixed position", "Moving"]}, {"desc": "From which angle did you shoot the video?", "name": "Shoot Angle", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Frontal recording", "Tight angle: 10-40 degree", "Wide angle: 40-70 degree"]}, {"desc": "From which distance did you shoot the video?", "name": "Distance", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Near/Selfie", "Mid (3-6 ft)", "Far (>6 ft)"]}, {"desc": "What is the video lighting direction?", "name": "Lighting Direction", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Front lit", "Side lit", "Back lit"]}, {"desc": "What is the video background?", "name": "Background", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Outdoors", "In office", "At home", "Plain background"]}, {"desc": "What is the topic in your speech?", "name": "Topic", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Arts and Media", "Business", "Education", "Entertainment", "Food/Eating", "Nutrition", "Healthcare ", "High School Life", "Mental Health", "News", "Technology", "Morals and Ethics", "Phones and Apps", "Sports", "Science"]}]
```

My task is: "Each value, name, desc from JSON need to be stored as one row in the table".

Example:
id: 1, desc: "How many people does the video contain?"
id: 2, desc: "What is the camera position?"
etc.

I use query:

```
SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values FROM source.table AS c, c.inputs AS d;
```

And got an ERROR: navigation on column "inputs" is not allowed as it is not SUPER type

And query:

`SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values FROM source.table AS c, JSON_PARSE(c.inputs) AS d;`

gives me another error: "function expression in FROM may not refer to other relations of same query level"

But when I have created test JSON as:

```
CREATE TABLE test_parse_json_super
(
  id smallint,
  details super
);
 
INSERT INTO test_parse_json_super VALUES(1, JSON_PARSE('[{"desc": "How many people does the video contain?", "name": "Number of People", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Only 1", "2-3", "3+"]}, {"desc": "What is the camera position?", "name": "Movement", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Fixed position", "Moving"]}, {"desc": "From which angle did you shoot the video?", "name": "Shoot Angle", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Frontal recording", "Tight angle: 10-40 degree", "Wide angle: 40-70 degree"]}, {"desc": "From which distance did you shoot the video?", "name": "Distance", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Near/Selfie", "Mid (3-6 ft)", "Far (>6 ft)"]}, {"desc": "What is the video lighting direction?", "name": "Lighting Direction", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Front lit", "Side lit", "Back lit"]}, {"desc": "What is the video background?", "name": "Background", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Outdoors", "In office", "At home", "Plain background"]}, {"desc": "What is the topic in your speech?", "name": "Topic", "type": "dropdown", "values": ["", "Arts and Media", "Business", "Education", "Entertainment", "Food/Eating", "Nutrition", "Healthcare ", "High School Life", "Mental Health", "News", "Technology", "Morals and Ethics", "Phones and Apps", "Sports", "Science"]}]'));
```

and use query `"SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values FROM test_parse_json_super AS c, c.details AS d;"` from official RedShift docs - it's work fine and all data from JSON is parsing to each rows and JSON is correct.

How I can fix query for work with my real data?

Thnx.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue.  The json has to be parsed in a created table before use, and cannot be referenced via a CTE or subquery and then used.  Therefore I believe the answer is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table_with_super 
AS 
(
  SELECT c.*, 
         JSON_PARSE(c.inputs) AS inputs_json_super 
  FROM source.table c
);

SELECT c.*, 
  json_row.desc, 
  json_row.name, 
  json_row.values
FROM my_table_with_super as c,
     c.inputs_json_super as json_row;
```

Comment: Ah this was exactly my problem. Querying data from S3 and trying to be clever and split+unnest it all in one go, but it doesn't like it. Split into a temporary table, then unnest into another table, now it's happy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are confusing the concepts of SUPER data type for sub-select.  You cannot cast a string to super (using JSON_PARSE) and then use it as the source of the FROM clause at the same level of the query.  I don't have a complete understanding of your situation but I think something like this should get you closer:

```
SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values 
FROM (
    SELECT *, JSON_PARSE(inputs) AS inputs_super
    FROM source.table 
    ) AS c, 
JSON_PARSE(c.inputs_super) AS d
;
```

(This is an off the cuff response to show structure so please forgive any syntax issues)

Comment: Thnx for you advice. But it doesn't work: "    Query results
    Table details

Query 
ELAPSED TIME: 00 m 10 s
ERROR: function json_parse(super) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: You question indicated that inputs is a string, not a super.  This error indicates that inputs is of type super.  Please clarify the data types you are using.

Comment: Gotcha - it's the 2nd json_parse.  Yep my error, untested code

Comment: Can you help me another moment. After we had parsed JSON above I have a column "values" with list like ["Agree","Disagree"] etc (can be more or less than 2 items). I need parse this list of values and add each of items from list to each row with other data. Example: desc: "210396", values: "Agree", desc: "210396", values: "Disagree". Do you understand?

Comment: I think you are describing the "list_agg() within group" function. This joins the values of a column from multiple rows together into a single string with delimiter.  Do have have intention correct? See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html

Comment: I think I need list unagg :)

Comment: So you have a string that is a list and need to divide it into rows?

Comment: In this case you want to use REGEXP_SUBSTR() with the "occurrence" parameter.  You need a dataset (table or generated in the SQL) of the number 1 through the maximum number of elements that can be in the string.  CROSS JOIN your table with strings with this numbers table.  Use the number to extract the Nth occurrence from the string.  Lastly remove any rows where the REGEXP_SUBSTR() produces NULL

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I have a problem - this list ("values" column) is a SUPER after query above and REGEXP_SUBSTR() don't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136509/redshift-function-json-extract-array-element-textsuper-integer-boolean-does

Comment: Ok you have a jain super dictionary and need to pull the dict keys, right?  Sorry I don't know how to do that one

Comment: I have written a post about it. Link above

Answer (score 0):

It will be more correct:

```
SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values 
FROM (
    SELECT id, created, JSON_PARSE(inputs) AS inputs_super
    FROM source.table
    WHERE prompttype = 'input'
    ) AS c, 
c.inputs_super AS d                                                      
;
```