# RedShift: function json_extract_array_element_text(super, integer, boolean) does not exist

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a data to RedShift:

```
id: 210396
created: 2021-09-01 05:42:15.80726
inputs_super: [{"desc":" Please check the pledge box, Pledge content","name":"pledge","type":"dropdown","values":["Agree","Disagree"]}]
desc: " Please check the pledge box, Pledge content"
name: "pledge"
values: ["Agree","Disagree"]
```

I need to parse list of "values" at RedShift and create row for each of list's items.

Example:

```
id: 210396
created: 2021-09-01 05:42:15.80726
inputs_super: [{"desc":" Please check the pledge box, Pledge content","name":"pledge","type":"dropdown","values":["Agree","Disagree"]}]
desc: " Please check the pledge box, Pledge content"
name: "pledge"
values: ["Agree"]

id: 210396
created: 2021-09-01 05:42:15.80726
inputs_super: [{"desc":" Please check the pledge box, Pledge content","name":"pledge","type":"dropdown","values":["Agree","Disagree"]}]
desc: " Please check the pledge box, Pledge content"
name: "pledge"
values: ["Disagree"]
```

I create this query to do this operation:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE seq_0_to_100 AS (
    SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    -- I am stopping here, you could easily generate this as a VIEW with 100+ real rows...
);
                                                       
                                                       
WITH all_values AS (
SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values
FROM (
    SELECT id, created, JSON_PARSE(inputs) AS inputs_super
    FROM course.table
    WHERE prompttype = 'input'
    ) AS c, 
c.inputs_super AS d
ORDER BY created DESC                                                       
LIMIT 10
), split_values AS (
SELECT id, json_extract_array_element_text(values, seq.i, True) AS size
FROM all_values, seq_0_to_100 AS seq
WHERE seq.i < JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(values)
)                                             
SELECT * FROM  split_values;
```

But I got an error on the last step when try to split list (on "split_values" step):

ERROR: function json_extract_array_element_text(super, integer, boolean) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

May be you know how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that values is still of type super and needs to be a string.  The function to convert super to string is json_serialize().

I was curious so I built a test case from your question.  Here's my working version:

```
drop table super;
create table super as select  210396 as id, '2021-09-01 05:42:15.80726'::timestamp as created, 
    '[{"desc":" Please check the pledge box, Pledge content","name":"pledge","type":"dropdown","values":["Agree","Disagree"]}]'::text as inputs,
  'Please check the pledge box, Pledge content' as desc, 'pledge' as name;
  
drop table seq_0_to_100;
CREATE TEMP TABLE seq_0_to_100 AS (
    SELECT 0 AS i UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    -- I am stopping here, you could easily generate this as a VIEW with 100+ real rows...
);
                                                       
                                                       
WITH all_values AS (
SELECT c.*, d.desc, d.name, d.values
FROM (
    SELECT id, created, JSON_PARSE(inputs) AS inputs_super
    FROM super
    --WHERE prompttype = 'input'
    ) AS c, 
c.inputs_super AS d
ORDER BY created DESC                                                       
--LIMIT 10
), split_values AS (
SELECT id, i, json_serialize(values), json_extract_array_element_text(json_serialize(values), seq.i) AS size
FROM all_values, seq_0_to_100 AS seq
WHERE seq.i < JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(json_serialize(values))
)                                             
SELECT * FROM  split_values;
```